# Subzero Hazelcast compression

Tags: hazelcast, kryo

Currently, I am using [subzero](https://github.com/jerrinot/subzero) for the Hazelcast serialization and since I want to support forward and backward domain compatibility, so I am setting the **subzero** `defaultSerializer= CompatibleFieldSerializer` ([CompatibleFieldSerializer](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/blob/498cd2b9765d3af8c77d3c4b1ede993fe3dd45a7/src/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/serializers/CompatibleFieldSerializer.java)) and I noticed that the size of the data inserted to Hazelcast is almost the same as the actual data size. Is this related to the serializer? Since if I use the default FieldSerializer I am able to see the size of the data reduced more than 70%.